# It shows The method toStringbyPrice(double) is undefined for the type JTextArea。I dont know how to deal with

Tags: java

```
      public void show()
```

// it just some part of my code

```
{
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Candles");
                    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);                       
                    JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
                    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                    JMenu menu=new JMenu("Menu");
                    JMenu menu2=new JMenu("Edit");
                    menuBar.add(menu);
                    menuBar.add(menu2);
                    JMenuItem menuItem1=new JMenuItem("Open");
                    menu.add(menuItem1);    
                    menuItem1.addActionListener(new FileMenuHandler(frame));        
                    JMenuItem menuItem2=new JMenuItem("Quit");
                    menu.add(menuItem2);    
                    menuItem2.addActionListener(new FileMenuHandler(frame));        
                    JMenuItem menuItem=new JMenuItem("Search");
                    menu2.add(menuItem);    
                    menuItem.addActionListener(new EditMenuHandler(frame));

                    frame.add(unsortedCandles);
                    frame.add(sortedCandles);
                    frame.setLayout(layout);
                    frame.setSize(400, 400);
                    frame.setLocation(200, 200);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`
                    //frame.pack();
```

// use pack here will make the window very small
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }

```
            public class EditMenuHandler implements ActionListener{
                        JFrame jFrame;
                        float inputNumber;
                        public EditMenuHandler (JFrame jf) {
                            jFrame = jf;
                        }

                    }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                                String menuName = event.getActionCommand();
                                if(menuName.equals("Search")) {
                                    double inputPrice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter:"));              
                                    JTextArea newArea = new JTextArea();
                                    newArea.append(sortedCandles.toStringbyPrice(inputPrice));
```

// i have some problem in this part .It shows The method toStringbyPrice(double) is undefined for the type JTextArea。I dont know how to deal with.

```
 remove(unsortedCandles);
                                        remove(sortedCandles);
                                        add(newArea);
                                        pack();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Is it? You don't show what `sortedCandles` is, but it's likely the error message means exactly what it says. I mean, `toStringbyPrice` (which should be `toStringByPrice`) likely *isn't* a method on `JTextArea` and is instead one of your own methods. Hard to say. Can't see your code.

Comment: In which class is the `toStringbyPrice` method defined?